# finding common multiple for list of doubles such that they will become integers

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I'm currently using [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) to solve a system of linear equations through LU/QR decomposition. The output is correct but the solution is sometimes outputted with decimals. For instance:

```
    //2x + y + 3z = 1
    //2x + 6y + 8z = 3
    //6x + 8y + 18z = 5
    double[][] lhsArray = {{2,1,3}, {2,6,8},{6,8,18}};
    double[] rhsArray = {1,3,5};

    //Creating Matrix Objects with arrays
    Matrix lhs = new Matrix(lhsArray);
    Matrix rhs = new Matrix(rhsArray, rhsArray.length);

    //Calculate Solved Matrix
    Matrix ans = lhs.solve(rhs);

    //Printing Answers
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
        System.out.println(ans.get(i, 0));
```

will output the following solution:

```
x = 0.3000000000000001
y = 0.4
z = -5.551115123125783E-17
```

the numbers look odd but I'm guessing it's due to loss of precision during calculations. It's close enough to the actual answer which is x = 3/10, y = 2/5, and z = 0. How can I find a common multiple for all the numbers outputted so that they will all become integers? (e.g. **10** * 3/10 = 3, **10** * 2/5=4, **10** * 0=0, so I'd like to method to find **10**)

I've considered this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58493/algorithm-to-find-a-common-multiplier-to-convert-decimal-numbers-to-whole-number) except it's not practical as I'm working with doubles, so values may be very 'long' due to repeating decimals (like the x and y values above).

I'm open to using something other than JAMA if someone has a solution that can solve the system of equations so that the values are more manageable. Any suggestions?

Comment: you might wanna use math.round(), since the extra digits are very small

Comment: Wouldn't the multiplier just be the lcm of all the coefficients? (Assuming all the coefficients are integers.) Or some factor of the lcm, but you could work that out afterwards by taking the gcd of the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to convert a floating point number to the minimal integer fraction (then once you do it for all numbers, you just find the LCD of the denominators). Every rational number has either terminating or repeating fractional part.

If the number has the form x=a.b and b has length n and then terminates (in the binary form), then 0.b = 2^-n and x = a+b/2^n = (a*2^n+b)/2^n. If a*2^n+b has m trailing binary 0s, your minimal fraction is ((a*2^n+b)/2^m) / 2^(n-m)

For repeating b with period p of length n (i.e. 0.b = 0.pppp..) [EDIT: the period doesn't have to start immediately after the point actually, i.e. it can be 0.cppp, in which case you can just temporarily multiply it by 2^c_length and later adjust the final fraction], there's a [good explanation on wikipeadia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal#Converting_repeating_decimals_to_fractions)

The gist of it as follows

```
0.b*2^n - 0.b = o.b*(2^n-1) = p
0.b = p/(2^n-1)
x = a+p/(2^n-1) = (a*(2^n-1)+p) / (2^n-1)
```

Then you factorize the numerator and the denominator and remove repeating multiples to find the shortest form.

Of course, it's probably worth doing only if you identify the period length n to be relatively short. Since it can get long even for small numbers, you might just as well bruteforce all possible denominators (up to a certain size) until you find one that produces an 'integer enough' product.

Comment: i think this is a really good solution! (I'd upvote but not enough rep yet) But as you say, it's only practical for small period lengths and I'm dealing with fairly large ones. In fact, I get an overflow exception for certain values.

Comment: if I bruteforce it, how might you determine if the value is 'integer enough'?

Comment: well, if the double x in question is a direct result of an a/b division (which is a fairly strong if), then theoretically the maximum difference of x*b from a is b*2^(x's_exponent-53) (i.e. just the precision bit after the last one). I guess you can use some larger tolerance for practical purposes (though it's probably still a good idea to make it relative to the x's exponent)

Answer (score 0):

A double will never 'become' an integer. 
Are you after *a* common multiple, or the smallest common multiple? It is anybody's guess what will be in the lower decimals, so I'd say just decide how many decimals you are interested in, multiply by a power of 10 accordingly, and then round.

Comment: @Old_Morality I'd prefer the smallest common multiple but thats not too important as I can reduce it later on by finding the GCD. How can I decide on the number of decimal places? Consider 1.87457 and 3.75 and I'm trying to find the common multiple to turn both into integers. If I round to 3 decimal places, I'd get 1.875 which would produce 8 as a common multiple (1.875*8 = 15, 3.75*8 =30) where as if i round to 1 decimal place, I'd get 1.9 which would produce a completely different answer.

Comment: That is probably the essence of it, and no amount of programming will fix that. If you find these 2 numbers: 0.33..3 and 0.11..1, you might as well have found 0.33..4 and 0.11..2. There is no meaning in the precise value of a floating point number. So you need to round it somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I would consider using the float data type for your values. When you use a float data type to get x it computes to 0.3. By doing this you will lose the long string of 0s and the trailing 1. Something like this: float x = 3/10f;
By doing this your precision will be uniform across all the variables.

Comment: this made the values much more manageable for me. combining this with @Anton's solution I actually got it. Thanks! Not sure why you got downoted